# Sending embedded image in email using sendgrid in node.js

Tags: node.js, image, sendmail, sendgrid

I want to send an email with embedded image from node js using sendgrid. I use the following code

```
var base64Img = require('base64-img');
const sgMail = require('@sendgrid/mail');
var base64str = base64_encode("logo.png");

function base64_encode(file) {
  var bitmap = fs.readFileSync(file);
  return new Buffer(bitmap).toString("base64");
}
sendMail(["example1@gmail.com"],base64str);
function sendMail(emails,data)
{
sendgrid.send({
      to: emails[0],
      from: 'example2@gmail.com',
      subject: 'Test Mail',
      attachments: [
       {
        filename: "logo.png",
        type : "image/png",
        content: data,
        content_id: "myimagecid",
        disposition : "inline"
       }
     ],
       html:"Please look on the image <img src='content_id:myimagecid'  alt='no image found'/>",

  }, function (err) {
    if (err) {
      response.json({ message: 'Selected but Mail not sended and Error is'+err });
      console.log("Mail error",err);

    } else {
      console.log("Success Mail sended ");
      response.json({ message: 'Selected and Mail sended' });
    }
  });

}
```

Here I used  **disposition : "inline"** but still the image send as an attachment. Can anyone help me please?

Comment: Hi, this is Libor from linkedin. I did not use sendgrid for years, so I really cant help, sorry.

Comment: Did you fix this issue?

Answer (score 0):

You are defining your file as an attachment, therefore it ends up being that. 
Instead, you need to define it as a file, and then call it in your html code.

If you read through this article...

https://sendgrid.com/blog/embedding-images-emails-facts/ ,

... you'll see this is actually not a recommended approach. Rather you may want to embed your base64'd image straight into your html.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I changed it to files and check but this time image is not send to the mail even as attachment. Also base64 is not working for me. If u have any code snippet or code reference please share here

Comment: it appears gmail does not display embedded base64 images, so the cid method is probably the only one that's supported by all. let me know if you solved the problem, @MuthuPrasanth. thanks!

Answer (score 0):

If anyone is still struggling with sending dynamic image (image that changes with every email you send, example: maybe some personalised image or image of a QR having some link) you can use the third step mentioned in [Sendgrid article](https://sendgrid.com/blog/embedding-images-emails-facts/). Following are the steps with some example code snippet (I am sending a QR image with some invite link):

[**Note**: This is only if you want to embed the image in email body. Otherwise you can just pass it as an attachment and Gmail can load base64 encoded attachments!]

1. Upload the image generated to some storage service like S3 or dropbox

```js
 const base64EncodedQRCode = await this.qrCodeService.generateQRCode(payload.inviteUrl);
const buffer = Buffer.from(base64EncodedQRCode.replace(/^data:image\/\w+;base64,/, ""), "base64");

await this.s3Service.uploadToS3(folderPath, fileName, buffer, "base64", "image/png");
```

2. If you are passing html in the sendgrid request, add an `img` tag with the url for the uploaded image

```js
await sendgrid.send({
      to: payload.email,
      from: SENDER_EMAIL,
      subject: 'Test Mail',
       html:"Please look on the image <img src='https://<bucketName>.s3.amazonaws.com/<folderPath>/<fileName>.png'  alt='no image found'/>",

  });
```

3. If you are using templates, add a block of image in the template and keep the src dynamic.

```js
await sendgrid.send({
      to: payload.email,
      from: SENDER_EMAIL,
      templateId: templateID,
      dynamicTemplateData: {
        qrCodeImageUrl: "https://<bucketName>.s3.amazonaws.com/<folderPath>/<fileName>.png",
      },
    })
```

```html
<td style="font-size:6px; line-height:10px; padding:0px 0px 0px 0px;" valign="top" align="center"><img class="max-width" border="0" style="display:block; color:#000000; text-decoration:none; font-family:Helvetica, arial, sans-serif; font-size:16px; max-width:50% !important; width:50%; height:auto !important;" width="300" alt="" data-proportionally-constrained="true" data-responsive="true" src="{{qrCodeImageUrl}}"></td>
```

Answer (score -1):

If you don't have many images you can use `Inline Embedding`

```
<img alt="My Image" src="data:image/jpeg;base64,/9j/4S/+RXhpZgAATU0AKgAAAAgACAESAAMAENkDZ5u8/61a+X...more encoding" />
```

Comment: base64 is not working for some email clients, gmail is part of those –